# XGBRegressor constantly returns 100% accuracy

Tags: python, xgboost

I am trying to fit an XGBRegressor() on an unbalanced dataset (97% / 3%) and evaluate results, however having issues with generating the right evaluation metrics.

I chose SMOTE to oversample my target variable.

```
X = multiSdata.filter(['col1', 'col2','col3','col4', 'col5','col6','col7','col8',
                       'col9','col10','col11','col12','col13','col14','col15','col16','col17',
                       'col18','col19','col20','col21','col22','col23','col24'])
# retain the original feature labels
feature_labels = pd.Series(X.columns.values)

X.head(5)
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test  =   train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.3, random_state=27)

print( "Predictor - Training : ", X_train.shape, "Predictor - Testing : ", X_test.shape, "Target - Training : ", y_train.shape, "Target - Testing : ", y_test.shape )
```

Output:
Predictor - Training :  (876742, 24) Predictor - Testing :  (375747, 24) Target - Training :  (876742,) Target - Testing :  (375747,)

```
y_train.value_counts()
```

output:
0    824518
1     52224
Name: target, dtype: int64

```
sm = SMOTE(random_state = 27, ratio = 1.0)
X_train, y_train = sm.fit_sample(X_train.values, y_train.values)

np.bincount(y_train)
```

Output:
array([824518, 824518])

```
xgb = XGBRegressor(learning_rate =0.1,
 n_estimators=1000,
 max_depth=5,
 min_child_weight=1,
 gamma=0.1,
 subsample=0.8,
 colsample_bytree=0.8,
 objective= 'binary:logistic',
 nthread=4,
 scale_pos_weight=1,
 seed=21,
 eval_metric = ['auc','error'])
```

```
SMOTE = xreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```
X_test = X_test.as_matrix()
smote_pred = SMOTE.predict(X_test)
```

```
import xgboost as xgb
params = {'learning_rate' : 0.1,
 'n_estimators':1000,
 'max_depth':5,
 'min_child_weight':1,
 'gamma':0.1,'subsampl':0.8,'colsample_bytre':0.8, 'objectiv': 'binary:logistic',
 'nthread':4,'scale_pos_weight':1,'seed':21,'eval_metric':['auc','error']}
xg_train = xgb.DMatrix(data=X_train, label=y_train);
cv_results = xgb.cv(params,xg_train,num_boost_round=10,nfold=5,early_stopping_rounds=10)
cv_results
```

[image]

I am trying to use cross validation, however was not able to use it with XGBRegressor, instead used the xgboost and generated a DMatrix from X_train and y_train. Unsure if this could be causing the 100% accuracy, which is definitely wrong.

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to further trouble shoot why the model is not producing correct predictions.

Comment: Please provide a working example, including the imports and some example data if possible. If you want to use sklearn for cross-validation, you may want to consider their gradient boosting implementation ```sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier```

Could the problem be using ```SMOTE.predict(X_test)``` instead of ```.predict_proba()```?

Comment: It's hard to say what's causing the issue in this particular case. It's most likely a leakage. You probably forgot to drop the labels from the training data.

Comment: @AdarshChavakula I wish it was the case. I have checked if target was left by mistake but it is not included.

Comment: Have you also tried balancing by setting scale_pos_weight to sum(negative instances) / sum(positive instances) ?

Answer (score 0):

Oversampling may be creating leaky new cases, effectively duplicates of test set cases. Having left out test set untouched as you did may not prevent this. Only deduplication of the combined train plus test.

You can consider undersampling instead (no new leaks introduced, but still possible) if this is feasible. Neither of these sampling methods should affect accuracy that much if done correctly, so deduplication is strongly advised.

As for cross-validation, make sure you remove duplicates first, for the same reasons.